# Interpretation lm R independent categorical variable

Tags: r, interpretation, independence

I understand how to interpret dummy variables etc., but I have got trouble of interpreting a independent categorical variable.

This is my output:

```
Coefficients:
                            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                  4.24185    0.21154  20.052  < 2e-16 ***
children_1                  -0.14762    0.09982  -1.479  0.13934    
children_2                  -0.16486    0.10780  -1.529  0.12635    
children_3                  -0.46407    0.17585  -2.639  0.00838 ** 
gender_female                0.11652    0.07299   1.596  0.11055
```

The variable children has the levels 0 - no children, 1, 2 and 3 for the count. My dependent variable is satisfaction with life. I think I have to say: If a person has one child, then the satisfaction with life decreases in expectation by -0.14762 units in contrast to the reference category 0. Is this rigth?

Thank you

Comment: Pretty much, satisfaction for the reference group (0) is 4.24 something, for 1 child it is lower by 0.14 somethings (on average).

Comment: Is your satisfaction variable continuous?

Comment: Why is the number of children a factor, and not a numerical variable?